# Sort Array by Alpabetical order using SelectionSort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, netbeans, compare

I am referencing my code to mathbits website on SelectionSorting, changing the variables accordingly from the examples `int` to `String` for my case, and adding in sort by alphabetical order as well.

Below is my current code for `SelectionSort` of students by `lastName`:

```
public static void SelectionSort(Student[] st) {

        int i, j, first;
        String temp;
        String jLastName = "";
        String firstLastName = "";
        String iLastName ="";

        for (i = st.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            first = 0;   
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
            {
                if (st[j].getLastName() != null) {

                    jLastName=st[j].getLastName();

                    if (st[first].getLastName() != null) {

                        firstLastName = st[first].getLastName();

                        if ((jLastName.compareToIgnoreCase(firstLastName)) < 0) {
                            first = j;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            iLastName = st[i].getLastName();
            temp = firstLastName;
            firstLastName = iLastName;
            iLastName = temp;

        }
    }
```

Pardon me for the naming of the variables.
The code does not give me error. However, the output does not show that it has been sorted according to alpabetical order. May I know which part have I made a mistake in? Thank you

Comment: well do you realize that you don't change the value of st[i] at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm is for sorting in descending order.

```
temp = st[ first ]; 
st[ first ] = st[ i ];
st[ i ] = temp;
```